# EF database-first generated form won't validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've just created a new controller, along with its CRUD forms, etc, with a database-first EF model/entity.

Its throwing a number of validation errors on save, but since the form has validators, I don't see why this would be so.

For reasons that are beyond me, I'm not getting any validation to happen at all.  It just goes right in to the saveChanges() call, which promptly fails.

Here's the edit form:

```
    @model StatementsApplication.DAL.StatementTask

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>StatementTask</legend>



        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sInitials)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sInitials)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sInitials)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dtCompleted)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtCompleted)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dtCompleted)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sGroupLabel)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sGroupLabel)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sGroupLabel)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nGroupSequence)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nGroupSequence)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nGroupSequence)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sTaskType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sTaskType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sTaskType)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sTaskLabel)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sTaskLabel)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sTaskLabel)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nTaskSequence)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nTaskSequence)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nTaskSequence)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and here's the generated model:

```
namespace StatementsApplication.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class StatementTask
    {
        public int StmtBatchID { get; set; }
        public string sInitials { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> dtCompleted { get; set; }
        public string sGroupLabel { get; set; }
        public double nGroupSequence { get; set; }
        public string sTaskType { get; set; }
        public string sTaskLabel { get; set; }
        public double nTaskSequence { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual StatementBatch tblStmtBatch { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here's the controller bits...

```
//
// GET: /StatementTask/Edit/5

public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    StatementTask statementtask = db.StatementTasks.Find(id);
    if (statementtask == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.StmtBatchID = new SelectList(db.StatementBatches, "ID", "sStatus", statementtask.StmtBatchID);
    return View(statementtask);
}

//
// POST: /StatementTask/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(StatementTask statementtask)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(statementtask).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.StmtBatchID = new SelectList(db.StatementBatches, "ID", "sStatus", statementtask.StmtBatchID);
    return View(statementtask);
}
```

Its a matter of some confusion for me as to why sInitials is throwing 'required' validation errors, as well as why sGroupLabel is throwing length validation errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) your model has no data validation annotations.  As such, MVC doesn't do any validation, because you're not telling it what to validate.

b) You don't mention what you are submitting.  Are you just submitting an empty form?

Comment: I agree, it does not have any validations, so its a mystery as to why I'm getting validation errors out of the submit..however, to answer your (b) question, I am editing a row with some data filled...a pre-existing row, with data generated by another process.

Comment: @reidLinden - There are 2 (or 3) levels of validation.  There's Client-side jquery validation, there's server side MVC validation, and then EF has validation on it's model attributes.  Are you using fluent mapping in your ef model?  Are you telling it some fields are required?

Comment: I'm pretty raw when it comes to asp.net/mvc stuff...so I can't even say that my lack of awareness of terms such as Fluent means I am not...I might be.  All I know is I have Generated my EF layer from an existing database.  I found the error with the max length.  I'd updated the table, but forgot to re-run the model refresh...but its still complaining about the sInitials..my only idea is that somehow, because the column has a NOT NULL constraint, (with a default '' value), when the empty field makes it back to the server, or the EF validation layer you mentioned..the empty is counted as null.

Comment: my guess appears to be correct. sInitials goes into the Edit View as "" (an empty string), but comes back to post the save as a null value.  Is there a better way to handle this than to just detect the case and reset to "" ?  That seems pretty fragile, so I anticipate theres a clever trick to make it work.

Comment: @reidLinden - the "clever trick" is that you should make the value nullable in the database if you're going to pass it null values.  Using empty strings is just asking for trouble.

Comment: hmm...I'll need to think on that some.  You're probably right, but I've got an awful lot of code that utilizes empty strings instead of null values.  Thanks!  Marking your answer as complete.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that Data Annotations will resolve this issue

```
   [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
   [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
   public object Note { get; set; }
```

via http://fendy-huang.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-pass-empty-string-in-entity.html